# How do you specify the width of a column that has been extruded from a point in arcscene?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I've extruded a set of points based on a z variable but I want to increase their width so they're easier to see.

Comment: Assuming 3D Analyst also extrudes polygons, buffer the points before extruding them.

Comment: As Bill recommends, you will have to buffer them.  If the points were not based on an variable attribute you could have used the 3D Simple marker symbol (Cylinder) and set the cylinder Z size to a desired value.